# Getting Code coverage for scala based batch jobs

Tags: scala, code-coverage, scoverage

I have a batch job developed in scala. I am triggering the job with a shell script and would like to measure the code coverage for the job.
The job is triggered after build creation.

How to the start scoverage after this job?

Comment: You may use **Scoverage**, link to the maven plugin: https://github.com/scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin

Comment: Actually its not part of the build process, rather running the job after the build created. I am using scoverage for unittests, but not sure how to instrument the coverage while running the scala jobs outside build process.

Comment: you mean some kind of integration testing? - I'm not an expert in testing, but I don't think you should measure code coverage on those, for example look at this: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24997/why-do-code-coverage-of-integration-test

Comment: Can you prepare simple example project similar to yours? It will be a lot easier to understand your setup with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can add below command in shell script to execute test and measure coverage:

```
sbt clean coverage test coverageReport
```

You can add below command to check if `coverage` is above minimum in `build.sbt`:

```
coverageMinimum := 80
coverageFailOnMinimum := true
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh, Thanks for your reply. Below are the steps i am following as of now: 1. Build application using maven. 2. Shell scripts are generated in target folder. 3. I am triggering the shell scripts to invoke scala jobs. Here my project is based on maven and also i dont have any clue on generating the coverage on job executions like these.